# Issues while compiling and executing C file which has Python embedded in C

Tags: python, c

I have a small C code, where in I embedded the Python code into C. Basically the idea is to execute a python function from C and get the required result from Python function to C. I have ran into many issues while compiling, more specific linker errors.
So I have to manually give a some paths and compile it, which looks like

first i need to do this,

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/aipir/anaconda3/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and then

```
 export PYTHONPATH='/home/aipir/anaconda3/lib/python3.8'
 export PYTHONHOME='/home/aipir/anaconda3/lib/python3.8'
```

Then compile the C file using

```
gcc -Wall -I/home/aipir/anaconda3/include/python3.8 main1.c -L/home/aipir/anaconda3/lib/ -lpython3.8
```

My code is to calculate the sum of two numbers by passing the arguments from C file to Python module and get the result back to C file.
Below python code:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a+b
```

Execution command is

```
./a.out cal add 23 45
```

Now the problem is when I try to import libs in Python

```
import pandas
import numpy
```

This results in error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I have done both `pip install pandas/numpy` and `conda install pandas/numpy` but still i am getting the same error when I execute from C File Execuable.
But when I run from Python Interpreter in the terminal, the import works with out any errors.

Also this is `sys.path`

```
['', '/home/aipir/anaconda3/lib/python3.8', '/home/aipir/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib/python38.zip', '/home/aipir/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib/python3.8', '/home/aipir/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload']
```

Please suggest a solution for this?
Thanks,
Harshavardhan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen due to many Python versions installed in your OS. If you want to remove some Python versions from your Linux it is difficult.
Simple solution is to do the same with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Cause it has only Python 3 and no Python 2. This should work. It worked for me.